# Using key value observation (KVO) with a set

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have a property called `savedArticles` that I would like to observe. As of now, it is declared as a Set as a property of a Controller type object as shown below:

```
@objc dynamic var savedArticles: Set<Article> = []
```

This does not work because "property cannot be marked `@objc` because its type cannot be represented in Objective-C".

**How should I changed `savedArticles` so that it can still be used as a set but also be observable?**

My first thought was to change the type of my property to NSSet but I couldn't manage to get this working and wasn't even sure if it was the right approach or not. Using this approach, I was forced to manually implelemnt the Hashable protocol for `Article`. I did that as follows

```
class Article: Hashable {
    static func == (lhs: Article, rhs: Article) -> Bool {
        return lhs.title == rhs.title && lhs.date == rhs.date && lhs.author == rhs.author
    }
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        title.hash(into: &hasher)
        date.hash(into: &hasher)
        author.hash(into: &hasher)
    }

    var title: String?
    var author: String?
    var description: String?
    var date: String?
}
```

Comment: A KVO observable set is a pretty bad idea, but the discussion in the links will elucidate. It would better to explain to us what problem you are really trying to solve.

Comment: @matt Thanks for the feedback. Sorry for the bad post. If you have time I would like to hear your advice.
I have a class called `ArticleController`. In this class I have a property called `savedArticles` (a set). A view controller called `SavedArticlesTableViewController` wants to know about any time a new article is saved so that it can refresh its table. I suppose I could accomplish this by sending a simple notificaiton. So, I observe any changes to `savedArticles`, and my observer (the table view) reloads itself.

Comment: Well so why not use a setter observer? What do you need KVO for? Or why not make the variable private and make the setter public?

Comment: thank you. And I just realized who you are and just want to say I love your books. I preordered Diving Deep into Ios13 on amazon.